given a positive and decreasing function, will its inverse be decreasing?
Given a positive function $f(x)>0$ such that $f'(x)<0$.
consider the domain $[0,1]$ and the range $[0,\infty)$
is there any proof that the inverse function  $y = f^{-1}(x)$ is DECREASING?
That is $ (f^{-1})'(x)<0, \forall x>0$?

What is the domain and range of the proposed function? You only give information about $f$ on the interval $(0, \infty)$, and if that is the domain then by definition the inverse is positive.

considering @SammyBlack's comment, i edited the question. what i'm really interested in is knowing whether i can tell if the inverse will be increasing or decreasing

The condition that $f'(x)<0$ is a stronger condition than that $f$ is decreasing. If the function is differentiable then the result follows immediately from the Inverse Function theorem.

Yes, and it follows from the chain rule that
$$
1 = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} f^{-1}\bigl(f(x)\bigr) 
= (f^{-1})'\bigl(f(x)\bigr) \cdot f'(x)
= (f^{-1})'(y) \cdot f'(x), 
$$
where we write $y = f(x)$ for convenience.
So,
$$
(f^{-1})'(y) = \frac{1}{f'(x)} < 0 
$$
which shows that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable, and $f$ is decreasing.

In fact, a stronger proposition is actually true. Without even assuming that $f$ is differentiable, as long as $f$ is strictly decreasing, then it is invertible and its inverse is strictly decreasing as well. There are many questions about similar statements on this site, e.g., this one where we assume that $f$ is continuous and conclude that $f^{-1}$ is as well.

To apply the chain rule, shouldn't you know a priori that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable? That does follow from the inverse function theorem, but maybe needs $f'$ to be continuous? I expect there's an easy argument by bounding the difference quotient since this in 1D
